# Using resources directly from Expansion file

Tags: andengine, apk-expansion-files

How to create texture directly from expansion files.
We get InputStream, now how to use this Input Stream. If I convert in bitmap and then use it start giving outofmemory.

I have tried

```
ZipResourceFile expansionFile = APKExpansionSupport.getAPKExpansionZipFile(appContext,
    mainVersion, patchVersion);

InputStream fileStream = expansionFile.getInputStream(pathToFileInsideZip);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create as follows:

```
File imageFile = new File(imagePath);
BitmapTextureAtlas mBitmapTextureAtlas = new BitmapTextureAtlas(
            activity.getTextureManager(), 1024, 1024, TextureOptions.BILINEAR);
IBitmapTextureAtlasSource fileTextureSource = FileBitmapTextureAtlasSource
                    .create(imageFile);
ITextureRegion textureRegion = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory
            .createFromSource(mBitmapTextureAtlas, fileTextureSource, 0, 0);
```

Memory management:

1. Give the texture Atlas size relative to your image size.
   For Example if your image size is 200X200 then give as 256 X 256 otherwise giving texture more makes wastage of memory.
2. And also unload the textures when ever these are not needed.